# How to get a count of all posts in foreach loop and split into fourths

Tags: loop, columns

I have this loop:

```
<?php
$categories = get_terms('my_category');
foreach ( $categories as $category ) :
?>
```

I want to split the posts into 4 separate div columns so that post titles will be alphabetical vertically like:

```
a | d | g | j
b | e | h | k
c | f | i | l
```

How do you get the total post count and divide evenly into fourths?

Edit: Here is the whole loop I'm working with

```
<?php
$categories = get_terms('archive_category');
foreach ( $categories as $category ) :
?>
<div>
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><h3><?php echo $count; ?><?php echo $category->name; ?></h3></a>
<div class="collapse" id="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>">
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
'post_type'  => array('custom_post', 'custom_post', 'custom_post'),
'taxonomy' => $category->taxonomy,
'term'  => $category->slug,
'numberposts' => -1,
'orderby'=>'title',
'order'=>'ASC'
));

foreach($posts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post); 
?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) won't get you the posts; it'll get the terms in a given taxonomy. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the name of the category and then outputting all the posts within the category underneath the category header.

Comment: You could achieve that layout with just CSS flexbox

Comment: I don't think there is a css solution to this. I tried column-count but the layout shifts when I expand content ( the links show when the category header is clicked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem couple years ago. Here's a gist I've published, which shows the basic idea how I solved the problem,https://gist.github.com/koskinenaa/4d8461116885c0e64d5ca167ae53434d

Applying the gist to your situation I think the solution could be something like this. I didn't test this so it might require some tweaking, but it should at least point you to the right direction. Of course you need to add relevant css for the `ul` elements to position them next to each other.

In my example I moved the term and post queries to their own helper functions, but this is just a matter of preference.

```
function archive_categories( string $tax ) {
  $categories = get_terms($tax);
  return ( $categories && is_array($categories) ) ? $categories: array();
}

function archive_category_posts_query( string $tax, string $term ) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type'   => array('custom_post', 'custom_post', 'custom_post'),
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby'     => 'title',
    'order'       => 'ASC'
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => $tax,
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => $term,
      ),
    ),
  );
  return new WP_Query($args);
}

$categories = archive_categories('archive_category');
$col_count = 4;

foreach ($categories as $category) :
  $category_posts_query = archive_category_posts_query($category->taxonomy, $category->slug);
  $post_count = $category_posts_query->found_posts;
  $posts_per_col = ceil( $post_count / $col_count );
  $i = 0;
  ?>
  <div>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $category->slug; ?>">
      <h3><?php echo $count; ?><?php echo $category->name; ?></h3>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>">
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $category_posts_query->posts as $category_post ) : 
          if ( $posts_per_col === $i ) {
            $i = 0; 
            echo '</ul><ul>';
          }
        ?>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php esc_url( get_the_permalink( $category_post->ID ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $category_post->post_title ); ?></a>
          </li>
        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- collapse -->
  </div> <!-- collapse wrapper -->
<?php endforeach;
```

**EDIT 5.2.2020**

Categories into columns? You mean something like this?

```
$categories = archive_categories('archive_category');
$category_count = count( $categories );
$col_count = 3;
$categories_per_col = $category_count > $col_count ? ceil( $category_count / $col_count ) : 1;
$column_index = 1;

echo '<div class="row">';
foreach ($categories as $category) :
  $category_posts_query = archive_category_posts_query($category->taxonomy, $category->slug);
  if ( $column_index > $col_count ) {
    $column_index = 1;
    echo '</div><div class="row">';
  }
  $classes = array(
    'column_1_of_' . $col_count,
    'column-' . $column_index,
  );
  ?>
  <div class="<?php echo implode( ' ', $classes ); ?>">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $category->slug; ?>">
      <h3><?php echo $category->count . ' ' . $category->name; ?></h3>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>">
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $category_posts_query->posts as $category_post ) : ?>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php esc_url( get_the_permalink( $category_post->ID ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $category_post->post_title ); ?></a>
          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- collapse -->
  </div> <!-- collapse wrapper -->
<?php $column_index++; endforeach;
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really close, but isn't quite what is needed in this instance. I made an edit to the code above which I hope shows what I am going for. Basically instead of being based on post_count it needs to be based on a category count. The category title is listed and then posts within the category are listed below. So categories need to spit into thirds rather than posts. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @semory So the categories should be the columns and posts just plain lists, right? I added another code example to my answer. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Thanks again! I was able to modify your last code sample to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is CSS and you've got a couple options!

```
<?php $categories = get_terms('my_category'); ?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ( $categories as $index => $category ): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

You can use Flexbox...

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 306px;
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

OR, you can use Text Columns

```
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Here's](https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/) a great resource with further details and codepens.

Comment: Thanks. These css solutions don't quite work. I can't use css3 columns because the layout shifts when content is expanded. The category header expands the the list of posts. flexbox doesn't work with 4 columns. I messed with it for a while.

Comment: If you can replicate your code in a codepen I'll fix it for you